# Angular js ng-change event not working when value changing from ouside the scope

Tags: angularjs

If i am changing value from ouside the scope ng-change event was not firing. Currently i am using AngularJS v1.3.1

Note : Previously i used AngularJS v1.2. That time it was working fine.

Comment: should be inside the scope...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats normal and it's intendet to be that way.
You have to call apply function. When changing something outsite the scope.

take a look:
http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/10/more-angularjs-magic-to-supercharge-your-webapp.html#apply-digest-and-phase